# Arrange different data set using matrix code

Tags: r

I'm trying to use repeat loop to generate 100 data set of Poisson Distribution  with sample size n=100 and I would like to arrange the result in by row and column but it is just show me repeating to show me the last set of data while not all the data set. At the same time I would also trying to figure out the way to get the mean, variance and MSE of the 100 data set.

```
set.seed(124)


a <- 1
repeat{
b = rpois(100, lambda = 3)
Storage100 <- matrix(data=b,nrow=100,ncol=1)
a = a+1
print(b)
if (a>100){break
  }
}
Storage100
```

I'm expecting that my 100 data set can be show like first set of data in first column, second set of data in second column.....

Answer (score 1):

Use `replicate` with `simplify` as `TRUE` to get matrix of dimension 100 X 100 where each column represents the distribution.

```
set.seed(124)
m1 <- replicate(100, matrix(data=rpois(100, lambda = 3),ncol = 1), simplify = TRUE)
```

To get the `mean` for each column we can use `colMeans` (thanks to @jay.sf)

```
colMeans(m1)
```

Comment: thanks for the code it is really helpful but I have 1 issue is that according to the code u provided the random data will be different for every times I'm trying to run it right? Can I prevent this to happen?

Comment: @KokLin do you want the same data every time in each column ? You can do `m1 <- matrix(data=rpois(100, lambda = 3),ncol = 1)` and then `m2 <- replicate(100, m1, simplify = TRUE)` ?

Comment: No, what I mean is that I would like to the same data for next time i run the code with previous one. Is that possible?

Comment: @KokLin Yes, you can set the seed with any number (same as in your attempt), so that you get the same matrix everytime. Check the updated answer.

Comment: thank every much. One more question what code should I use to find the variance for each column?

Comment: @KokLin Use `apply(m1, 2, var)` ?